# Lazy High Charts: cannot get pie chart to show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, lazy-high-charts

Following the directions [here](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts/wiki/Pie-Chart) (and correcting for the tag issues in the code sample) I am attempting to implement a pie chart in my app. I load the initial page but the pie chart does not load on the partial (I make it into the html.erb file). A lot of things are hard coded right now so for instance Chart Type, etc do not get passed back to the controller yet.

Can someone help point out where I went awry?

Controller:

```
  def dynamic_chart
    @chart_types = ChartType.all
    @user_visible_models = ["Asset","Asset Manufacturer","Asset Model", "Map","Campus","Tag","Room", "Room Monitor"]
    @date_ranges = ["Day", "Week", "Month"]
  end

  def gen_chart
    @rooms = Array.new
    Room.all.each do |room|
      @rooms << [room.name, room.asset_count]
    end

    @chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('pie') do |f|
      f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"pie" , :margin=> [50, 200, 60, 170]} )
      series = {
          :type=> 'pie',
          :name=> 'Asset by Rooms',
          :data=> @rooms
      }
      f.series(series)
      f.options[:title][:text] = "THA PIE"
      f.legend(:layout=> 'vertical',:style=> {:left=> 'auto', :bottom=> 'auto',:right=> '50px',:top=> '100px'})
      f.plot_options(:pie=>{
          :allowPointSelect=>true,
          :cursor=>"pointer" ,
          :dataLabels=>{
              :enabled=>true,
              :color=>"white",
              :style=>{
                  :font=>"13px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif"
              }
          }
      })
    end
```

dynamic_chart.html.erb

```
<%  javascript 'dynamic_chart'  %>

<div id="graph_controls">
  <%= form_tag('activate_reports/dynamic_chart', :class => "well form-inline") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:name, nil, :class => "input-small", :placeholder => "Report Name") %>
    <%= collection_select(:activate_report, :chart_type_id, @chart_types, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select chart") %>
    <%= label_tag :x_axis, "X:", :class => "control-label" %>
    <%= select :x_axis, nil, @user_visible_models, :prompt => true %>
    <%= label_tag :y_axis, "Y:", :class => "control-label" %>
    <%= select :y_axis, nil, @user_visible_models, :prompt => true %>
    <%= select :date_range, nil, @date_ranges, :prompt => "Select a day" %>
    <%= link_to("Chart!", "#", :remote => true, :class => "btn", :onclick => 'gen_chart()') %>
  <% end %>

</div>

<div id="chart_area"></div>
```

_gen_chart.html.erb Partial:

```
<%= high_chart("chart_area", @chart) %>
```

gen_chart js function used to initiate the new chart

```
function gen_chart(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/activate_reports/gen_chart",
        type: "GET",
        data: {},
        dataType: "html"
    });
}
```